# How to set Command Line arguments with C# in Mono IDE .

Tags: c#, mono

Hi I am trying to send two arguments with C# by using MONO IDE , But I am unbale to do that . I am getting the following error .

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
  at Command.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /media/EE76D9DA76D9A39D/C#/Command.cs:6 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
  at Command.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /media/EE76D9DA76D9A39D/C#/Command.cs:6
```

Here is my program :

```
using System;
class Command
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} , Welcome to {1}",args[0],args[1]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: How are you trying to set the arguments?

Comment: I'd like to pass them from IDE .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you mean the MonoDevelop as IDE. If that's true, then go to your project options (either by right clicking on the project and selecting options or via the Project menu and (project name) options position), then go to Run > General and you can put desired parameters in the Parameters edit box.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling this program ?

If you are just hitting Run in the IDE, it will be run without arguments. Then args will be an empty string array ( `string[0]`), and therefore you get the exception.

Try calling it from the command line and pass two arguments.

Comment: I am calling with RUN in MONO . may i set command line argument passing with the IDE ?

Comment: Yes. I don't have MonoDevelop handy right now, but you should be able to go into properties for the project, find command line arguments (or similar) and enter two arguments.

Comment: Thank you . But I am pretty new to MONO and I am not doing this program as a project . i am just doing it in a file . I cant see anything like properties here . Thanks for your information . :D

Comment: sorry sir . May be it does but i cant find here . its not a project and its just a file .

Comment: I have got your point , I need to create a project even to run a single file . Then only i can send some arguments from the options as mentioned by you and  in below answer . Thank you sir .